# EMI in non-conducting materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Is magnetic flux observed in non-conducting materials too? If yes then EMF should be induced in non-conducting materials per Faraday's law. However, I have read that "motional and rotational" EMF cannot be induced in non-conducting materials because the latter do not have free charges. Still, I cannot seem to get over whether they can induce EMF or not in other cases of EMI.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: What is "non-conducting", really? No material has infinite resistance, so where do you draw the line between conducting and non-conducting? All materials will conduct charges at sufficiently high voltages. The fields generated by neutron stars should be strong enough to rip charged particles, electrons or otherwise, out of any matter you can encounter on Earth. But you can't expect a simple textbook to be bogged down by scenarios that are so extreme and exotic that they are not measurable in any earth bound case I can think of.

Comment: @DKNguyen thank you for answering, but sorry i dont understand why did you take the topic from what i asked to whether "non-conducting" materials exist or not(did i frame my question incorrectly?), i wasn't the one who drew the line between conducting and non-conducting, it was physics and its approach, non conducting materials are just assumptions to understand the real scenarios layer by layer; I wanted to know the answer to my question under that assumption only.

Comment: It sounded to me like you were asking whether something has truly zero effects, while simultaneously using some idealizations (which cannot truly exist).

Comment: @DKNguyen let me try again, i wanted to ask assuming that non conducting materials are taken into consideration, can EMF be induced in them as per EMI's laws? Because magnetic flux says no where that material should be conducting for it to be defined and hence EMF should also be induced in non conducting materials, thats what i thought so needed clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To induce current the material should be capable of sustaining the current. It's pretty straight forward! You can't have current in non-conductors so you can't have EMI in them, EMI is nothing but induced current.

Comment: sorry to say, the basis for EMI is not induced current, it is induced EMF(voltage), EMI is observed in an open loop also despite the fact that current cannot be induced in an open loop